# How to Integrate a IBM Infosphere Streams application with IBM Bluemix Watson?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot, ibm-streams

I am new to IBM InfoSphere Streams and I am using InfoSphere Streams Quick start edition. I am trying develop an application which takes input from Watson IoT devices. I went through an tutorial which tell us about getting the data to the InfoSphere Streams console they just used an **.sab** file. They used **com.ibm.streamsx.iot** tool kit to get the data from Watson IoT devices. I am trying to download and install streams.iot toolkit to develop application using Streams studio. But I can't find the correct location of the **streams.iot**  toolkit. I can't find the way to configure this toolkit to Stream studio as well. Can anyone tell me steps for downloading, installing and usage of the **com.ibm.streamsx.iot** in Streams studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IOT toolkit is designed as a microservice.  As documented by the IOT toolkit, to connect to your device, all you need to do is to submit the SAB file using the Streams Console.  The toolkit acts as a bridge between the Watson IOT Platform and the Streams application.  The services employs a pub-sub model.  To receive events in your Streams application, you need to subscribe to your device events from the IOT bridge.

The Readme from here provides good background description about the IOT toolkit:
https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.iot

To work with the IOT toolkit in Streams Studio:

1. Download a release from here: https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.iot/releases/tag/v0.8.0
2. Follow the instructions as described in the release installation document.  Download the IOT toolkit and all its dependencies.
3. To allow your application to find these toolkits, in Streams Studio, open the Streams Explorer View.
4. Expand the "InfoSphere Streams Installation" tree item, and keep expanding until you see the "Toolkit Locations" item
5. Right click on the "Toolkit Locations" item, right click -> Add Toolkit Location
6. In the resulting dialog, browse for the directory where your toolkits are located.  Click OK.  Repeat for each of the toolkits needed.

You are now ready to write a Streams Application that uses the IOT toolkit.

To learn more about Streams Studio, check out this Streams Studio Quick Start Guide:
https://developer.ibm.com/streamsdev/docs/studio-quick-start/

Check out this video:
https://youtu.be/ir_nUv4maL4

Here's a Starter Kit that demonstrates how to integrate Streams with Watson IOT Platform:
https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.waterConservation.starterKit

Comment: Thank you Samantha Chan for giving step by step explanation and links to solve the problem........... Now I can able to connect with the Watson IoT Cloud Devices using Streams analytic's console.....